# jedis llen result not equal redis llen

Tags: java, lua, redis, jedis

I meet a very weird problem about Redis and its Java client Jedis. I have two list in Redis named `workMQ` and `backupMQ`, when I execute `llen workMQ` in redis-cli, it returns `16`. However when I execute `jedis.llen("workMQ")` in Java code with Jedis, it returns `0`. But when new data coming by run `jedis.lpush("workMQ", "data")`in Java codes, the Redis `llen workMQ` become `1`.  Why `jedis.llen("workMQ")` couldn't recognize the remain `16` data items in this  list?

Before this weird problem occur, I did `rpoplpush` operate with Lua script as follows.

`eval "for i = 1, 10 do\r redis.call('rpoplpush', 'backupMQ', 'workMQ')\r end" 0`

Actually this Lua script have some errors, the correct one is

`eval "for i = 1, 10 do\r redis.call('rpoplpush', KEYS[1], KEYS[2])\r end" 2 backupMQ workMQ`

Maybe there is some type error between Redis and Lua. I have executed both of these Lua scripts, but still can't work.

PS: My Jedis client's version is 2.7.2, the latest stable version from Jedis Github.

Thanks for your time.

**Solved:** After one night, the Redis server magically recognized workMQ's items length, and all is fine. It's really strange.

Answer (score 0):

1. This weird thing cannot happen. You must got something very wrong. For example, redis-cli can accept command like "llen(workMQ)" ? Or do you actually mean "llen workMQ"?

   I think it's very likely you are using jedis to operate on a different list key than on redis-cli!
2. The lua problem is simple, you shoud return a value (at your will) at the end of lua script. And if it still didn't work, post the detailed error information for me!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

1. It happens. ```llen(workMQ)``` is a spell mistake, actually I'm using ```llen workMQ``` in redis-cli.

2. When I run this Lua script with redis.call, no errors output.